# How to remove NA pattern from string

Tags: r, string

I have a R dataframe column with following text

```
ClientID          Recom
 ABC              1:Teck|Scrip:ABC|Call:Buy||2:NA|Scrip:NA|Call:NA
 DEF              1:CG|Scrip:WERT|Call:Buy||2:CDGS|Scrip:QWS|Call:Buy||3:IT|Scrip:QAS|Call:Buy||4:NA|Scrip:NA|Call:NA||5:NA|Scrip:NA|Call:NA
 WER              1:CDGS|Scrip:WERT|Call:Sell||2:IT|Scrip:QWS|Call:Buy||3:Industrials|Scrip:QAS|Call:Buy||4:NA|Scrip:NA|Call:NA
```

I want to remove NA's from above pattern. Desired dataframe would be

```
ClientID          Recom
 ABC              1:Teck|Scrip:ABC|Call:Buy||
 DEF              1:CG|Scrip:WERT|Call:Buy||2:CDGS|Scrip:QWS|Call:Buy||3:IT|Scrip:QAS|Call:Buy||
 WER              1:CDGS|Scrip:WERT|Call:Sell||2:IT|Scrip:QWS|Call:Buy||3:Industrials|Scrip:QAS|Call:Buy||
```

I am using following gsub in R,but it does not seem to work.

```
df$Recom <- gsub("\\s*[|]+\\NA\\s+.*", "", df$Recom)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your strings are setup seem to have all NA after the first NA. If this is the case then,

```
gsub('[0-9]+:NA.*', '', df$Recom)
```

You can also use `strsplit` and `grepl`,

```
sapply(strsplit(df$Recom, '\\|\\|'), function(i)paste(i[!grepl('NA', i)], collapse = '||'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df$Recom <- lapply( strsplit( df$Recom, split = '||', fixed = TRUE),
                    grep, 
                    pattern = 'NA',
                    invert = TRUE,
                    value = TRUE )

df
#   ClientID   Recom
# 1      ABC   1:Teck|Scrip:ABC|Call:Buy
# 2      DEF   1:CG|Scrip:WERT|Call:Buy, 2:CDGS|Scrip:QWS|Call:Buy, 3:IT|Scrip:QAS|Call:Buy
# 3      WER   1:CDGS|Scrip:WERT|Call:Sell, 2:IT|Scrip:QWS|Call:Buy, 3:Industrials|Scrip:QAS|Call:Buy
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ClientID = c("ABC", "DEF", "WER"), 
                     Recom = c("1:Teck|Scrip:ABC|Call:Buy||2:NA|Scrip:NA|Call:NA", 
                               "1:CG|Scrip:WERT|Call:Buy||2:CDGS|Scrip:QWS|Call:Buy||3:IT|Scrip:QAS|Call:Buy||4:NA|Scrip:NA|Call:NA||5:NA|Scrip:NA|Call:NA", 
                               "1:CDGS|Scrip:WERT|Call:Sell||2:IT|Scrip:QWS|Call:Buy||3:Industrials|Scrip:QAS|Call:Buy||4:NA|Scrip:NA|Call:NA"
                     )), 
                .Names = c("ClientID", "Recom"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
                class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have several kinds of information embedded in the `Recom`-column. To clean your data, you could also do:

```
library(splitstackshape) # will automatically also load the 'data.table' package
dt <- cSplit(
        cSplit(
          cSplit(df, 'Recom', sep = '||', 'long'), 
          'Recom', sep = '|', 'long'
        ),
        'Recom', sep = ':', 'wide'
      )[Recom_2 != 'NA'
        ][, num := cumsum(grepl('\\d+', Recom_1)), ClientID
          ][grepl('\\d+', Recom_1), Recom_1 := 'kind']

dcast(dt, ClientID + num ~ Recom_1, value.var = 'Recom_2')
```

which gives:

```
   ClientID num Call Scrip        kind
1:      ABC   1  Buy   ABC        Teck
2:      DEF   1  Buy  WERT          CG
3:      DEF   2  Buy   QWS        CDGS
4:      DEF   3  Buy   QAS          IT
5:      WER   1 Sell  WERT        CDGS
6:      WER   2  Buy   QWS          IT
7:      WER   3  Buy   QAS Industrials
```